# PHP round up value

Tags: php

I have value like this

```
13/12 = 1.083333333
```

what i want is

```
13/12 = 2
```

I already tried round,it not what I expected.

Please anyone help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+round+up --> https://www.php.net/ceil

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Comment: that what i looking for thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `ceil()` function. It automatically rounds any partial values up to the next whole integer.

```php
$value = 13/12; 
$rounded = ceil($value); 
echo "Value: " . $rounded;
```

PHP also has a corresponding `floor()` function, which rounds down to the nearest whole integer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `ceil` function.

Comment: @samabcde It does, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thx for your feedback, I should try to comment on giving more details instead of flag as not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

like this?
(round(13/12,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)

Comment: That doesn't do what OP wants. It affects the rounding of `x.5` numbers (i.e. the exact half-way point between integers) and nothing else. Your code results in `1.0`; OP wants `2.0`.